# Root login doesn't work with Synaptic and Apper

Tags: debian, login, root, synaptic

I have an odd problem. I have tried to use Synaptic so I can install a package. The system asks for the root password but won't accept it. I can start a terminal window and start `su` with the root password and start Synaptic in `su` and it comes just fine. The same for Apper except it won't start in `su` for GUI reasons.

What must I do to correct this?

I am using Debian 9 stretch with KDE.

Comment: Are you trying to run synaptic with `sudo`?  Either way I'm guessing it's trying to use `sudo`.  In which case it's actually prompting for your user password and not the root password.  It could also be that your user is not an authorized sudoer.

Comment: To run Apper in recent Kubuntu I need to use `env 'DISPLAY=$DISPLAY' 'XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY' KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true apper`

Answer (score 0):

Privileged users can run synaptic through:

```
$ synaptic-pkexec
```

It will prompt for user password.